# Is it Possible to Add to TSQL Cursor?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given a simple cursor statement:

```
DECLARE vend_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT * FROM Purchasing.Vendor
    --say my Purchasing.Vendor table did not have 'Company ABC', 'Company F'
    --can I explicitly add 'Company ABC' and 'Company F' to the Cursor without
    --adding them to the database?
OPEN vend_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM vend_cursor;
```

Is it possible to add explicit values for the cursor to iterate through?

In reality, my application of this answers the obvious question of "why on earth would you not just add them to the database?" Just seeing what the syntax would look like to add to the cursor directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    DECLARE vend_cursor CURSOR
        FOR SELECT * FROM Purchasing.Vendor
            UNION ALL select .... 'Company ABC'
            UNION ALL select .... 'Company F'
    --say my Purchasing.Vendor table did not have 'Company ABC', 'Company F'
    --can I explicitly add 'Company ABC' and 'Company F' to the Cursor without
    --adding them to the database?
   OPEN vend_cursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM vend_cursor;
```